# Delta v of a trans-Mars injection (TMI)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, rocket-science, solar-system

Why does it only take about 600 m/s more than Earth's escape velocity to have an encounter with Mars while it takes much more [Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v) [v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget) (about 3 km/s) from a solar orbit (same as Earth orbit) to have an encounter with Mars?

What explains this difference?

Is it the Oberth effect or something else that explains this?

Comment: Presumably to reduce speed when approaching Sun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems related to the Oberth effect. Starting from the solar orbit, we need $\Delta v$ to enter an orbit to Mars. By energy conservation the velocity of the spaceship at launch from Earth has to be
$$v_0 = \sqrt{v_{\text{esc}}^2+\Delta v^2} \ ,$$
where $v_{\text{esc}}$ is the escape velocity. For $v_{\text{esc}} \gg \Delta v$, we find that the $\Delta v^{\prime}$ on top of the escape velocity is
$$\Delta v^{\prime} \simeq \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Delta v^2}{v_{\text{esc}}} \ .$$
This formula relates your Delta-v's in your question. We observe that $\Delta v^{\prime}$ becomes smaller the bigger the escape velocity from Earth. Bigger escape velocity means that you're deeper in the gravitational well. By the Oberth effect, a small Delta-v deep in the gravitational well has a bigger effect outside of the well.

In fact, irrespectively of the above approximation, we always have
$$\Delta v^{\prime} = \sqrt{v_{\text{esc}}^2+\Delta v^2}-v_{\text{esc}} \leqslant \Delta v \ .$$